# How to deploy a Django app locally on a windows xp machine?

Tags: python, django, django-deployment

I've got a small python 3 application which I'd like to use on a Windows XP machine. Now, the python shell is not that user-friendly, so I decided to build a GUI for it. I've tried using PyQt (with Qt designer) and TkInter, but I don't like working with them.

In search for alternatives, I thought about Django. I've worked on a project with Django once and I like the fact that I can use HTML to format the way the app looks. Oh, and I'm in love with how easy it is to implement the admin functionality.

However, it looks like deploying a Django application locally on a Windows XP machine isn't even possible. I've read the most recent Django documentation and it states nothing about doing such a thing.

If my question is still vague: I'd like to deploy a Django web app locally to use in a browser like Internet Explorer on a Windows XP machine. The installation should be 'plug-and-play'. The application relies on a csv database, so nothing too fancy there. I don't want the user to have them install Python or other dependensies himself. Ultimately, the user should only have to click on the shortcut which opens Internet Explorer which displays the app.

**EDIT:** The target system has no internet access.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Windows' environment, but on top of my head the easiest option is to deploy it on the web so it can be accessed in the Windows' machine by clicking a link. Or consider [packaging your app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app) which you can automate the installation process.

Comment: @mckuok, I forgot to mention the target system has no access to the internet.

Comment: [Packaging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app) it would be good

Comment: Check out `py2exe`. It lets you create Windows executable files from Python files.

Comment: Packaging looks interesting, @mckuok. If I understand it right, the target system still needs python with pip installed, which is a little issue.

Comment: py2exe won't do the job, @xyres. However, pyinstaller can do something explained in [this somewhat vague wiki article](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django).

Comment: Does someone have experiences with [bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/django)?